# Null-pointer exception when i call a method

Tags: java, class, arraylist, resultset

i'm getting a null pointer exception when i call my two methods. And i have no idea, why i get it. when i check the code it seems right

this is my HentbestillingsordreHandler class

```
public class HentbestillingsordreHandler extends JPanel{

private Connection con = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private HentbestillingsordreRegistrer ho;
private ArrayList<HentbestillingsordreRegistrer> hbor = new ArrayList<HentbestillingsordreRegistrer>();

HentbestillingsordreHandler() {

}

public void Hentbestillingsordre(){
    KaldSQL ks = new KaldSQL();
    try {
        con = ks.connectNow();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ResultSet rs = ks.Hentalleordreliste(con);
    try {
        while(rs.next()){
            String status = "";
            if(rs.getInt("BestillingsStatus") == 1){
                status = "Leveret";
            }else{
                status = "Ikke Leveret";
            }
            System.out.println(status);
            HentbestillingsordreRegistrer ho = new HentbestillingsordreRegistrer(
                    rs.getInt("BestillingsID"),
                    rs.getString("BestillingsStatus"),
                    rs.getInt("ModtagetAf"),
                    rs.getInt("Vare"),
                    rs.getInt("Antal"));

                    hbor.add(ho);
                    System.out.println(ho);

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}   
public void printBestillingsordre(){

        for(HentbestillingsordreRegistrer hentbestillingsordreRegistrer: hbor){
        String temp = "";
        temp += ho.getLeverandoerID()+" \n";
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

}
```

}

my kaldsql

```
public ResultSet Hentalleordreliste(Connection con){

    ResultSet Hentalleordreliste = null;

    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select varebestillinger.BestillingsID, " +
                "varebestillinger.LeverandoerID, "+
                "varebestillinger.BestillingsStatus, varebestillinger.ModtagetAf, "+
                "varebestillingsliste.Vare, " +
                "varebestillingsliste.Antal from varebestillinger left outer join " +
                "varebestillingsliste on  ListeID = BestillingsID");
                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
                Hentalleordreliste = result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Hentalleordreliste;


}
```

and this is my class HentbestillingsordreRegistrer

```
int LeverandoerID;
String BestillingsStatus;
int ModtagetAf;
int Vare;
int Antal;

public HentbestillingsordreRegistrer(int LeverandoerID, String BestillingsStatus, int ModtagetAf,int Vare,int Antal){
    this.LeverandoerID = LeverandoerID;
    this.BestillingsStatus = BestillingsStatus;
    this.ModtagetAf = ModtagetAf;
    this.Antal = Antal;
}

public int getLeverandoerID() {
    return LeverandoerID;
}

public void setLeverandoerID(int leverandoerID) {
    LeverandoerID = leverandoerID;
}

public String getBestillingsStatus() {
    return BestillingsStatus;
}

public void setBestillingsStatus(String bestillingsStatus) {
    BestillingsStatus = bestillingsStatus;
}

public int getModtagetAf() {
    return ModtagetAf;
}

public void setModtagetAf(int modtagetAf) {
    ModtagetAf = modtagetAf;
}

public int getVare() {
    return Vare;
}

public void setVare(int vare) {
    Vare = vare;
}

public int getAntal() {
    return Antal;
}

public void setAntal(int antal) {
    Antal = antal;
}
```

and when i call it i type this

```
    HentbestillingsordreHandler hboh = null;
hboh.Hentbestillingsordre();
hboh.printBestillingsordre();
```

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace as well, please?

Comment: the last 3 lines of code in your post clearly show that you are trying to call methods on `null`, and not on any object instances. See _username tbd_ answer to fix it. You are using Swing and JDBC, but that error is on the Hello World difficulty level.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use

```
HentbestillingsordreHandler hboh = null;
```

Instead, try

```
HentbestillingsordreHandler hboh = new HentbestillingsordreHandler();
```

When you call `new HentbestillingsordreHandler()`, you're creating a new `HentbestillingsordreHandler` object that will be stored somewhere in the computer's memory; you're then telling `hboh` to point to that particular piece of memory to be used whenever you access `hboh`.

The first statement, however, simply points `hboh` to a useless (and unreachable) point of the computer's memory; so at runtime, when you try to access `hboh`, you get a Null Pointer Exception, since the variable `hboh` is "Pointing" to a non-existent piece of memory.

Comment: I can now call the Hentbestillingsordre() but i still get a error and i nullpointer exception on temp += ho.getLeverandoerID()+" \n";

Comment: @user1880497 try replacing the code `HentbestillingsordreRegistrer ho = new` with simply `ho = new`.

Comment: private HentbestillingsordreRegistrer ho = new HentbestillingsordreRegistrer(); will not work because it needs parameter inside

Comment: problem found. thakns for making me going

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the name of the method as well as a variale inside it with the same name ::

```
public ResultSet Hentalleordreliste(Connection con){
ResultSet result = null;

    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select varebestillinger.BestillingsID, " +
                "varebestillinger.LeverandoerID, "+
                "varebestillinger.BestillingsStatus, varebestillinger.ModtagetAf, "+
                "varebestillingsliste.Vare, " +
                "varebestillingsliste.Antal from varebestillinger left outer join " +
                "varebestillingsliste on  ListeID = BestillingsID");
                result = statement.executeQuery();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;


}
```

Comment: @jlordo: I dont know, why was the -1,
As you see the code of OP, inside the method 'Hentalleordreliste' he has declared a variable with the same name as Hentalleordreliste.
So I pointed out this...

Comment: it is allowed to have local variables with the same name as the method, this will compile and work: `String foo() { String foo = "abc"; return foo; }` your answer is not helpful to the solution of OPs problem, nor any other problem.

Answer (score 0):

Java as opposed to Objective-C for example, doesn't allow method invocations on null references. So in general you have to initialize your reference with an object instance before trying to call a method on it.

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerExceptions are usually pretty easy to figure out. In the stacktrace you get the class and line number where the exception occurred. In your case it should be the line `hboh.Hentbestillingsordre()`. Using that information you can check where a value was assigned to the variable. Your assignment is `HentbestillingsordreHandler hboh = null`. Since you cannot make any method calls on `null` you get the exception.

In some cases you do not need any attributes of the objects for the method. In that case you can make the method `static`. You would call it with `HentbestillingsordreHandler.Hentbestillingsordre()` then, without the need for an instance of that class.